# how to handle pointer in for loop

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers, strlen

This throws an error id returned 1 error status. The loop is working but I cant print the final concatenated string. When i try to print the final string it does nothing.

```
char str1[50], str2[50], str[100];
char *p1, *p2, *p3;
int i = 0, j = 0;

p1 = &str1[0];
p2 = &str2[0];
p3 = &str[0];

printf("enter a string:");
gets(str1);

printf("enter a string:");
gets(str2);

while (i <= strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)) {
    if (i != strlen(str1)) {
        *(p3 + i) = *(p1 + i);
        i++;
    } else {
        *(p3 + i) = *(p2 + j);
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917)

Comment: "but i cant print the final concatenated string" - why not show the code which does the printing? Also, are you adding a NUL terminator correctly?

Comment: and where are you printing, exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of describing your code which did not work, can you show it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need to see a [mcve] for this problem. Also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @SouravGhosh How many times do you have to welcome the new user? :)

Comment: @machine_1 Otherwise I'll be branded as enemy of the new users and tagged as unwelcoming.

Comment: What happened to good-old `strcat` function ?

Comment: It's called the Welcome Wagon for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

This check here is wrong:

```
if(i!=strlen(str1))
```

When `i` is bigger than `strlen(str1)` it will get false again, but it is supposed to stay true. Change it to this:

```
if (i < strlen(str1))
```

Furthermore, you're not increasing `i` in the `else` block. This is going to cause an endless loop with ever-growing `j`, at least until the undefined behavior will cause your program to exit, possibly through an access violation. Try this instead:

```
else {
    *(p3 + i) = *(p2 + j);
    i++; // increase i in both cases
    j++;
}
```

Or better yet, make it unconditional. For instance, you could take the `i++` out of the body change the loop to this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str1) + strlen(str2); i++)
```

Also, may I interest you in the array subscript notation? Instead of this:

```
if (i < strlen(str1)) {
    *(p3 + i) = *(p1 + i);
}
```

Do this:

```
if (i < strlen(str1)) {
    p3[i] = p1[i];
}
```

It's much cleaner this way and people who will work with your code will appreciate it.

Comment: `// increase i in both cases`..rather, make it unconditional.

Comment: And please do suggest the array subscript notation: `p3[i]` & `p2[j]`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh good idea. I edited the answer to include suggesting a `for` loop with an `i++`, I guess that would be a clean approach.

Comment: @machine_1 Great suggestion, added it to the answer. I have to admit, looking at the `*(p3 + i) = *(p1 + i)` construct takes me some time to figure out what's going on.